# How do I redirect a page to "example.php"?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect

I have a simple project to code. In homepage I have some images. at background I am querying a file called "check.php" every 5 seconds using Ajax. And in check.php some data is fetched from database and if data is equal to 0 i want to redirect the whole site to "example.php" but if the data is equal to 1 I just want to update ajax response div with a text called "no change".

**Problem:** 
Whenever I am trying to do so it is not redirecting to "example.php" rather it is showing example.php in ajax response div.
I am using header("Location:example.php");  for this.

My codes:

```
//function auto for ct fetch starts

function reload_ct() {



var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
     var c_user = document.getElementById('c_name').value;
   xmlhttp.open("GET","check.php?cu=" + c_user,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
window.setInterval(reload_ct, 100);
//function auto for ct fetch ends
```

Comment: you need to test the ajax response and change window.location.href

Comment: I see you're setting an interval for 100ms. If the user's latency is slower than that you can start to stack requests. I'd recommend using `setTimeout` and setting a new timeout each time the AJAX response is returned. That way only one request will be pending at a time.

Comment: i am new to jquery and ajax so i am not geeting much more. So please edit my above code and write it how it should be also i have to send a variable c_user which is shown above in my code.

Comment: Did you want it to occur every 5 seconds, or 10 times a second? Every 5 seconds should be 5000, rather than 100. See the answer I posted.

Comment: the time can be any 5sec or 10 sec i just want you to edit my above code becoz also i have a variable to send to check.php

Answer (score 2):

This should work (in jQuery):

```
$.post('check.php',{'c_user':c_user})
$.done(function(data) {

if(data == '0'){
window.location.href = "example.php";
}

});
```

The general format is

```
$.post('URL_SENDING_TO',function (data returned from request) {

dosomething();

});
```

If you want to send data, you can use `.done`, like this:

```
$.post('URL_SENDING_TO',{'datatosend':'value1','datatosend2':'value2'})
.done(function (data returned from request) {

dosomething();

});
```

Of, if you'd like to do it without jQuery, this should work (reference http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_database):

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText == '0') {
            window.location.href = "example.php";
        }
    }
}

var time_five_sec = setInterval(
    function () { 
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "check.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("c_user=" + c_user);
    }, 5000);
```

If you want to change the last function to a setTimeout (as Jasper recommended), you could write:

```
function timed_ajax_request() {
    setTimeout(function () { ajaxrequest() }, 5000);
}

function ajaxrequest() {
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "check.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("c_user=" + c_user);
    timed_ajax_request();
}
timed_ajax_request();
```

This will send it in a loop, where it called the function `timed_ajax_request` first, then when the ajax request is sent, it called `timed_ajax_request` again, since it's a `Timeout`, it'll wait 5000 ms (or 5 seconds) before calling the request.

If you want to user `GET` instead of `POST,` change the lines:

```
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "check.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("c_user=" + c_user);
```

to:

```
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "check.php?c_user=" + c_user, true);
    xmlhttp.send("c_user=" + c_user);
```

And that should work the same. The same applies for jQuery, change it from:

```
$.post('check.php',{'c_user':c_user})
$.done(function(data) {

if(data == '0'){
window.location.href = "example.php";
}

});
```

to:

```
$.get('check.php',{'c_user':c_user})
$.done(function(data) {

if(data == '0'){
window.location.href = "example.php";
}

});
```

So, in conclusion, to do exactly what you wanted to do in your question, including Jasper's recommendation, you would write:

```
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        if (xmlhttp.responseText == '0') {
            window.location.href = "example.php";
        }
    }
}

function timed_ajax_request() {
    setTimeout(function () { ajaxrequest() }, 5000);
}

function ajaxrequest() {
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "check.php?cu=" + c_user, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    timed_ajax_request();
}
timed_ajax_request();
```

Comment: The OP doesn't suggest hes using jQuery.

Comment: I see, let me see if I can write it up in JavaScript

Comment: i am new to jquery and ajax so i am not getting much more. So please edit my above code and write it how it should be also i have to send a variable c_user to check.php which is shown above in my code Please help me.

Comment: The last section should be what you're looking for specifically. I would take some time to get to know `POST` and `GET` requests and their differences and to understand it (it's really just three sections, first is to set the xmlhttp request/object, second is to define what it does on data return, and the third is to actually send the request.

Answer (score 2):

I would pass the redirect comand from the AJAX php file back to the original file

return("go to example.php");

And then in the original file you grab this data and make a JS redirect if its = "go to example.php".